# Insert items after the header and before the footer in html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to insert some items after the header and before the footer sequentially.

base html:

```
<ul id="comments_notifications_list">
    <li>header</li>
    <li>footer</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying this code but the last item will be replaced:

```
$.each(comments, function(idx, obj){ 
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        $('ul#comments_notifications_list:not(:first-child)').append('<li>stuff</li>');
    });
});
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `after` or `insertAfter` jQuery methods.

Here is example of what you are trying to do:

```js
var comments = [1, 2, 3];

$("li:first-child").after($.map(comments, function(item){ 
        return "<li>Some value" + item + "</li>";
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="comments_notifications_list">
    <li>header</li>
    <li>footer</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: apparently the trick is the map. After or append is irrelevant. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way. Basically, you get the first child of ul tag by $('ul#comments_notifications_list').children().eq(0), then li tag will insert after this child. For more information about insertAfter(), you go to this link http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

```
 $.each(comments, function(idx, obj){ 
   $.each(obj, function(key, value){
    $('<li>stuff</li>').insertAfter($('ul#comments_notifications_list').children().eq(0));
});
```